# Find row number based on text in excel using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, epplus

I find some difficulty to fulfill my requirement in application. I use `EpPlus` library in my application with `c#`.

I just need to find a text from excel sheet and its corresponding row number.

IN my excel sheet I have a text `"Total",` I want to find which row that text contains and need to get that row number. Is it possible and not able to find in `epplus` documentation.

Thanks & Regards
Anil

Comment: I implemented search logic in a past project. Simply iterate over a range of cells searching for the text. It really helps if you have some idea where the text might be so you're not searching the entire sheet. It might be easier to provide an answer if you provide more details.

Comment: My text is some time in 8th position (row) some times in 20th position (row) . Its all depends on data. I just want to find this row number for making my for loop. If I am able to find this row , I can create a loop  from that position to read data. Hope you got my point. I can guarantee that it repeats only one time ( i mean 'Total')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use LINQ query to get your result

```
int rowStart = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row; 
int rowEnd = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

string cellRange = rowStart.ToString() + ":" + rowEnd.ToString();

var searchCell =from cell in worksheet.Cells[cellRange] //you can define your own range of cells for lookup
                 where cell.Value.ToString() == "Total"
                 select cell.Start.Row;

int rowNum = searchCell.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cell address in which your string is.

```
            foreach (var worksheetCell in worksheet.Cells)
            {
                if (worksheetCell.Value.ToString() == "Total")
                {
                    var worksheetCellFullAddress = worksheetCell.Address;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. How would you search a particular set of cells. Your code searches the whole sheet.